# Share object in views load twice

Tags: python, flask

I have a object need to share globally in views.py like this:

```
import stuff 

api = Blueprint('app', __name__, template_folder='templates')
shared_object = load_prefix_tree()

@api.route("/")
def index():

.....
```

which would works as i expected. But i notice that shared_object would load twice after start service. It seems related to the context(application and request) switching. Is there any way to make it only load once cause the shared_object would take about 30 mins to load. Thanks.

Comment: How are your running your application? Are you using the development server with the reloader enabled?

Comment: If you only want it to load once, is there any way to cache it? Why is it taking 30 minutes to load? What is it doing? 

Flask has: Flask.before_first_request which might help you.

Comment: I'm just using python app.py to start application. Is there any different start application by using WSGI or uWSGI ?

Comment: It's a huge prefix tree.